# Set control Background color using Dynamic Resource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my XAML

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicBG"/>
</Grid.Resources>
<Label name="MyLabel" Content="Hello" Background="{DynamicResource DynamicBG} />
```

So I have two questions:

**Q1:** How do I go about setting the `DynamicBG` key value to **Red** in my code now? (When the window loads, I'd like to set it to red)

**Q2:**  Is this how dynamic resources are supposed to be used?

Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To gain access to the `Resource` of the code must identify them in the file `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicBG" />
</Application.Resources>
```

`XAML example`

```
<Grid>       
    <Label Name="MyLabel" 
           Content="Hello" 
           Background="{DynamicResource DynamicBG}" />

    <Button Content="Change color"
            Width="100" 
            Height="30" 
            Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

The `Resource` can be changed in code line of the form:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MyResource"] = MyNewValue;
```

Example:

`Code behind`

```
// using ContentRendered event
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush MyBrush = Brushes.Aquamarine;

    // Set the value
    Application.Current.Resources["DynamicBG"] = MyBrush;         
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush MyBrush = Brushes.CadetBlue;

    // Set the value
    Application.Current.Resources["DynamicBG"] = MyBrush;
}
```

Principle, `DynamicResources` were designed, so they can be changed. Where to change - it is the task of the developer. In the case of `Color`, it is one of the most common methods. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx), for more information.

P. S. I recommend using `App.xaml`, because there have been cases where a `StaticResource` has been used successfully, but not `DynamicResource` (resources are placed in the `Window.Resources`). But after moving the resource in `App.xaml`, everything started to work.

Answer (score 8):

A1:
You should move "DynamicBG" to window resource and after that you can use `Resources` property in `Loaded` event handler:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyLabelDynamicResource.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicBG"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>    
        <Label Name="MyLabel" Content="Hello" Background="{DynamicResource DynamicBG}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resources["DynamicBG"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }      
}
```

A2: 
You should use dynamic resources when you want to change property in runtime.

Comment: thank you for your time and for answering in detail  , shame I have to pick only one answer. +1'd

Answer (score 3):

**A2: no.** To do what you are doing, it is better to use data binding. Have a property in your viewmodel indicating whether it's 'loaded', then bind the background to it with a suitable converter, or use a trigger. (If it's actually UI that is loading, add the property to the window.) Dynamic resources are used for theming and with templates, in the rare cases when a StaticResource lookup happens too early.