# How to change font-family of Combobox SelectedItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a style for ComboBox. and set Font-family for it.

Set font for Items but don't set for selected item.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionBoxTextTemplate">
     <TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=FontFamily}" Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IranSansFontFamily}"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
              <Grid>
                 <ToggleButton
                    Name="ToggleButton"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    ClickMode="Press"
                    Focusable="false"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}">
                 </ToggleButton>
                 <ContentPresenter
                    Name="ContentSite"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SelectionBoxTextTemplate}"
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom template selector, looking like this:

```
  public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate SelectedItemTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            bool selected = false;
            FrameworkElement fe = container as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null)
            {
                DependencyObject parent = fe.TemplatedParent;
                if (parent != null)
                {
                    ComboBox cbo = parent as ComboBox;
                    if (cbo != null)
                        selected = true;
                }
            }
            if (selected)
                return SelectedItemTemplate;
            else
                return ItemTemplate;
        }
    }
```

And in xaml:

```
 <ComboBox Name="cb" Height="28">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
                    <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Arial Black"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedItemTemplate>
                </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ComboBox>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i use this, but get error : `Cann't set SelectedItemTemplate while DisplayMemberPath is use`

Comment: DisplayMemberPath specifies name of a property to display. Since you have SelectedItemTemplate you can specify property name in its binding. So, instead of <ComboBox DisplayPath="Name> set <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding Name"}/></DataTemplate>

Comment: Could you post your original xaml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with a trigger on the IsSelected property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688785/2675101) for an example. It's for a ListBox but also applies to a ComboBox.