# How to bind background color to property "To" of a ColorAnimation?

Tags: wpf, binding, coloranimation

I have a color animation for a switch control and to let the background color to be changable I want to bind the `Background` property of the parent control to the `To` property of `ColorAnimation`. I tried a lot but no one worked. How can I do that?

**Switch control style:**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <Border x:Name="layer" Width="35" Height="20" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <Canvas Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="Gray" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="0" 
                                 Width="20" Height="20">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    </Ellipse>
                </Canvas>
            </Border>
        </Viewbox>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="layer" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                    To="LightGreen"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="circle"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                     To="15"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="layer" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                                        To="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="circle"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                     To="0"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Style>
```

**ColorAnimation part:**

```
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="layer" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    To="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not using binding in color animations,if you do you will be getting this error
 **"Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads"**, more info on this here:
[WPF Animation "Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669750/wpf-animation-cannot-freeze-this-storyboard-timeline-tree-for-use-across-thread).

Now if you want a way around, what you can do is make a static resource which represents the background color of your parent control like this:

```
 <Color  A="255"
            R="100"
            G="0"
            B="0"
            x:Key="resource" />
```

and then you can assign this resource to your color animation property like this:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="layer"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                                        To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=resource }" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But I want it to be customizable in the MainWindow.xaml. So the color should not be constant, when the control's background is changed, the `To` property should change too. Setting the color to a constant value as a resource cannot be changed.

Comment: then i guess you will have to do this in code behind.

Comment: @AliTor you can use dynamic resource then, here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502467/set-control-background-color-using-dynamic-resource-in-wpf

Comment: you can change the value of the dynamic resource on your checkbox checked event, setting it to the current background color of your control.