# How to create RGB slider to affect Hex color of DynamicResource?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create an RGB slider to affect the following code to change the value of the HEX color.

```
<Color x:Key="Color102">#FF001BFC</Color>
```

This code is mapped as a DynamicResouurce and I need a slider to adjust the value. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean a single slider to change Red, Green, Blue and perhaps also Alpha? No, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Clemens Nobody mentioned an alpha channel. Admittedly 16777216 pixels (plus border, padding etc.) is a lot of screen real estate, but nobody mentioned perfect resolution either. And maybe OP really wants three sliders.

Comment: I was thinking either 3 sliders or a Vertical gradient slider

Comment: Something like this link would do it. You'd need to have your 3 sliders trigger some code (event handler for value changed event, or in a property setter, etc) to update the resource. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502467/set-control-background-color-using-dynamic-resource-in-wpf

Comment: Ok. I have 3 sliders done. Now I need to bind them to a hex value. How can I achieve this? I want to be able to bind all 3 sliders to create a hex color value so when you adjust them it updated the hex color code.