# WPF - How could I change button color with changing resource of it

Tags: wpf, colors, resources

I have this on my resource of app.xaml

```
 <Color  x:Key="myColor">#1ba1e2</Color>
```

On my WPF project I have using it on my button:

```
void win_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
btn.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["mySolidColor"];
}
```

When I change resource of "mySolidColor", button isn't using new color

```
void changeColor(Colors color)
{
  Application.Current.Resources["mySolidColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
```

Please consider you are adding more than 1000 object like Button, you are using Resource as color, and I looking for a way that with changing color, past objects get's new color, is this possible ?

Comment: Use the Binding as DynamicResources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set control Background color using Dynamic Resource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502467/set-control-background-color-using-dynamic-resource-in-wpf)

Comment: Set the background in XAML, not code behind: `<Button Background="{DynamicResource mySolidColor}" />`. You should really be doing nothing in code behind, and writing a trigger in the XAML to update the Background.

Comment: @pix no it's not, my code works fine, but problem is I let user to change color during using app, so I have adding about 100 button, 100 grid and many thing, even I can changing color of resources, but past button is not using new colors

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have more than 1000 object, I have adding all of them dynamically, so I should to solve it with back-code

Comment: can't you add it in a clean way with sharedresource dictionary? (Are you doing plumbing code? :p)
I strongly recommand us to use the best practices... MVVV, sharedDictionary etc...

Comment: @Serareh Azimi you can define a template in xaml that is going to be applied automatically, without touching code behind

Comment: @SerarehAzimi That's exactly why you *don't* do it in code behind. But tell us enough about your problem for us to understand what your actual requirements are. Ask the complete question. Don't keep changing the question every time somebody answers it.

Comment: @pix please consider you are adding more than 1000 object like Button, you are using Resource as color, and I looking for a way that with changing color, past objects get's new color, is this possible ?

Comment: @DanieleSartori please write your answer

Comment: Then you must use a style with Button object as Target. And inside this style bind backgroundcolor as dynamicresource.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I not going to change anymore, sorry . but consider my 1000 object please. my project is dynamic project and user during work, visiting many page , and those data are showing until closing the app, so during changing color, I should to replace past color with new color.

Comment: @pix could you write your answer please

Comment: @SerarehAzimi pix's suggestion is probably the right thing to do. He and Daniele and I are all very much taking into account your thousands of buttons. This is how you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom style to target all the object you need ex: Button

```
<Color x:Key="YourColorNameKey">#1ba1e2</Color>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource YourColorNameKey}"/>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code so this will be just an example of what you can do:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="myResourcePath1"/>
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="myButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value ="{DynamicResource keyOfMyFavouriteColor}"/>
</Style>
```

Of course this require that you have written all your solid color brush inside a resource file (best choice if you have defined a lot of colors and template). You can style all your control easily with this approach, no matter if you have 500 buttons, all of them will have the same look.

Comment: Thanks, yes I should written all of my solid color brush inside a resource